# ZFS on Hetzner Rescue fails with `checking whether inode_owner_or_capable() takes user_ns... configure: error:`

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, hetzner

Normally, when booting into the Hetzner rescue system, using the 'zfs' command will automatically install zfs tooling inside the rescue system.
This is currently not working;

```
checking whether inode_owner_or_capable() takes user_ns... configure: error: 
        *** None of the expected "capability" interfaces were detected.
        *** This may be because your kernel version is newer than what is
        *** supported, or you are using a patched custom kernel with
        *** incompatible modifications.
        ***
        *** ZFS Version: zfs-2.1.11-1
        *** Compatible Kernels: 3.10 - 6.2

Install failed, please fix manually!
bash: line 499: zfs: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rescue kernel has been updated to 6.3, which is not yet supported by the latest zfs-on-linux release. This is slightly concerning.

The solution is to:

- select `Linux (old)` in the 'Operating system' selection box in the Hetzner robot interface 'Rescue' tab.
- Download the zfs download script, since it's not installed in the old rescue system:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tijszwinkels/966ec9b38b190bf80c2b2e4cfddf252a/raw/6d42ae592a49deb141ed4c42e6973eec5f4247f8/zfs`
```

(Please note that I added --no-check-certificate to the wget command, as this old version of wget does not download the zfs release otherwise. Unlikely, but this does make you vulnerable to mitm attacks)

- run it:

```
bash ./zfs
```

After this, the zfs tooling can be used as before.

Comment: "The Hetzner Rescue System is a Debian based Linux live environment" -- as far as I know Debian does not ship zfs by default, and Hetzner does not offer zfs as an option when deploying an instance or a volume, so I'm not sure why you're surprised.